# Storing in Session versus retrieving from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm very interested to hear the SO community opinion and recommended practice for this.

I currently have an ASP MVC application that validates a set of rules *(~100 rows (classes with 10 properties))* every time a user fills out a short form.  There are about 10 forms in the application and there are rarely ever more than 3 concurrent users on the application.

Currently I am storing all the rules in the Session variable that loads initially and is persisted throughout the forms.  Is this too much or bad practice to store in memory?  I did this to speed up the application, the load is pretty quick (less than a second) so I'm debating just loading as needed per form.

So - keep the rules table in memory *(session variable)* or load when validating each form?

Comment: Just how often your user access those forms? If, say, more than one minute per form, load on demand is already justifiable.

Comment: Good question, the forms average about 5 questions per form so for simplicity, I would say each form waits for postback about 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there are rarely ever more than 3 concurrent users on the application

That means you could store quite a lot in the session.

Your approach just doesn't 'scale' very well, that's why common wisdom will argue against it. But as long as your '3' doesn't become '300' or '3000', you're safe.

Comment: I completely agree Henk, and I think I could watch the use and if it ever grows to 10 - 20 concurrent users, the break out would not be bad at all since it is already abstracted.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am also considering Caching to make the variable application wide, that would solve the scalability factor, but rule changes would require a re-boot which isn't that desirable.

Comment: @Mark if you store it in the cache (System.Web.Caching or System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache in .NET 4), you could either give it an expiration, or have it monitor other objects (like a file) for changes. Either way, you would not have to restart the app. Any time the code reads the cache and the entry is missing, just re-load the cache.

Comment: Might be a reason to upgrade to .Net 4, but unfortunately we're on 3.5.  I'll definitely look into that though, sounds like the optimal solution.